# Datetime to Second Conversion

Tags: python

i have two datetime string like this '2010-08-31 04:35:50.176725' and '2010-09-05 04:35:50.176725' . now my question is how calculate seconds between two dates. i used time delta but its return in hour, minute formate. i want compltely in seconds.

Comment: Do you mean seconds since the Epoch?

Comment: Please look into http://docs.python.org/library/time.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import datetime as dt
import time

now=dt.datetime.now()
```

The Epoch is defined as 1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT.
You can find the number of seconds between `now` and the Epoch this way:

```
print(time.mktime(now.timetuple()))
# 1289565310.0
```

Or, if you wish to find the number of seconds between two dt.datetime objects:

```
now2=dt.datetime(2010,11,12,12,0,0)

def timestamp(date):
    return time.mktime(date.timetuple())

print(timestamp(now2)-timestamp(now))
# 15890.0
```

Comment: @Gautam: In that case please accept the answer using the tick on the left.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to find a difference between two dates in seconds?

If it's the case, then first get a `timedelta` (by simply subracting any two datetime objects with `-` operator). Then read the `seconds` field of the resulting object.

Comment: thank you ... but i have two datetime string like this '2010-08-31 04:35:50.176725' and '2010-09-05 04:35:50.176725' . now my question is how calculate seconds between two dates. i used time delta but its return in hour, minute formate. i want complte in seconds.

Comment: @Gautam - I gave you the answer to your question. But please update your question with the comment you posted here. It is now much clearer than your original question.

Comment: This answer is wrong.  The `seconds` field is only part of the data represented by a `timedelta` instance.